# Need to delete entire column in 2d list with regex function python

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop

So I have a CSV file that has 2 columns for "Gender" The second one is not needed. I **have** to use a regex function to do delete the 2nd Gender column.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import re

data = []

with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

print(data[0])
for i in range(len(data),):
    if re.match("Gender", data[i][11]):
        del data[i][11]
print(data[0])
print(data[1])



output:
['Name', 'Gender', 'SSN', 'Member Date', 'Phone', 'State', 'Zip', 'Email', 'Credit Card', 'Credit Card_Number', 'Credit Card Exp', 'Gender', 'Favorite Radio Station', 'Purchases Past 30 Days', 'Spent Past 30 Days', 'Purchases Past 6 Months', 'Spent Past 6 Months', 'Purchases Past 12 Months', 'Spent Past 12 Months']
['Name', 'Gender', 'SSN', 'Member Date', 'Phone', 'State', 'Zip', 'Email', 'Credit Card', 'Credit Card_Number', 'Credit Card Exp', 'Favorite Radio Station', 'Purchases Past 30 Days', 'Spent Past 30 Days', 'Purchases Past 6 Months', 'Spent Past 6 Months', 'Purchases Past 12 Months', 'Spent Past 12 Months']
['Mamie Mason', 'female', '459-69-6647', 'Mon Aug 01 2016 12:06:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)', '9472284457', 'Indiana', '82439-3619', 'm.masonason@gig.org', 'Visa', '4263xxxxxxxx1913', '09/23', 'female', 'WMMZ', '4', '$2149.81', '7', '$5188.75', '9', '$10756.500000000002']
```

I can not figure out why I am deleting column 11 in only the first row. (row 0) and not for every row.

I figured out I could use:

```
if re.match("Gender", data[0][11]):
    [j.pop(11) for j in data]
```

But I am trying to do it in a for loop because I am obviously not understanding them and I need to. I am in my first semester of school.

Thanks

Comment: Because every row thereafter doesn't have `"Gender"` in the 11th column, and you're making that check individually for each row? Your second solution should be sufficient, just put the `for` loop inside the `if`.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking but I was confused thinking it would just delete the entire column then exit the loop. I switched it and that worked. Thanks!

`if re.match("Gender", data[0][11]):`
    `for i in range(len(data)):`
        `del data[i][11]`